# Why doesn't my startup script to open a terminal work?

Tags: scripts

Just to fool around with script making, I made one that (I believe?) should open a terminal at startup:

```
#!/bin/bash
#start terminal at startup
#/usr/bin/gnome-terminal
```

i put it in the /etc/init.d directory, then ran this

```
update-rc.d myscript defaults
```

but absolutely nothing happens when i reboot my computer. Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Main error in your script is that in your third statement you have actually commented out the command to open the terminal. Kindly remove the "**#**" from the third statement. Meanwhile you can simply use **gnome-terminal** to activate it but it should be run as user itself. So that means adding it to update-rc won't work either. If you are more lean to terminal ways, well you can add your script in crontab and add it to user's crontab file with **reboot** constrain. This will run your script at start up. So I sum up as follows :
*Your file named as script.sh :*

```
#!/bin/bash
#start terminal at startup
gnome-terminal
```

Make script excutable by user using following command.

```
chmod u+x /path/to/script.sh
```

Now open up terminal and edit your user's crontab as follows :

```
crontab -e -u username
```

Add the following statement to the bottom of the file after making required changes accordingly.

```
@reboot /path/to/script.sh
```

Now reboot. That's it.

Comment: actually that was just a mistake i made while trying to format what I was typing on here, now I'm curious, why can't scripts in init.d run by themselves? I did the crontab thing for updatedb (which didn't work with a script) but I was mostly curious about just running scripts out of the init.d directory. Do I have to run crontab since it's a GUI applications as said before? Is there a way of doing that just through a script?

Comment: Unfortunately it's still not working even though I've done everything you said, however when I changed the permissions i did `chmod 777` instead of just adding execute if that has anything to do with it.

Answer (score 2):

#### Short answer:

`gnome-terminal` is a GUI application. Therefore it can only be run *as a user*. At the moment you are trying to run it, no user is logged in (yet). Put the (command to run the-) script in Startup Applications instead.

You don't *need* a script *at all* then however, you can add the command directly to Startup Applications.

This will start `gnome-terminal` once you log in.

Apart from that, your command to run `gnome-terminal` isn't correct. Should be `/usr/bin/gnome-terminal` (as mentioned by @steeldriver, thanks), or, since it is in `$PATH`, simply `gnome-terminal`.

Comment: ... also needs to remove the `#` from in front of the `gnome-terminal` command